# Is `this == &x` the correct way to determine if a pointer (this) and a reference (x) point to the same object?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a class, and inside this class, a function that takes as argument another instance of the same class. Inside this function I need to do some stuff, but only if the argument passed is not the same instance as the current one. Is the following code the correct way to do this?

```
class Foo
{
    void Foo::func(Foo &other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: why the close vote? please at least leave a comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/580628/104774 shows an example on handling self-assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `(ptr == &ref)` is the correct way of determining whether the pointer and reference are to the same object. (Technically it might fail, if `operator&` is overloaded, but that's a pretty unlikely situation, and one you'd obviously already be aware of, as the author of the class.)

Comment: as one of the deleted comments suggested, if `operator&` is overloaded, one can use `std::addressof`